# Looping inside a Stored procedure vs looping of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have to insert thousands of rows on some conditions in a table. which way will be faster. I am using c# Linq.
1:- calling stored procedure in a loop giving single row as input every time
1:- giving all rows as input to stored procedure and writing loop inside stored procedure.

Comment: Not writing any kind of loop is the fastest option. Please can you give an example of what you are trying to do? Perhaps there is a set based solution

Comment: I have a list of data in Linq object format. I need to write that data into sql server table based on certain conditions. Now should i pass whole list to stored proc as a table or create a stored proc which will take only one object a input an insert that to database. looping will be needed for both approaches. What i am asking in which way will be better. looping inside SP or executing Sp in loop.

Comment: Can't you pass the conditions / criteria into a stored proc and let that handle it.